# How to show saved wifi password in android

Tags: android, wifi, android-5.0-lollipop, android-wifi

I have Lenovo K3 Note having android lollipop 5.0 and want to show my saved wifi password.

I have seen below link contents but not helpful and getting the detail as provided.

[Link1](https://priceraja.com/blog/1656-smartphone-tips-how-to-find-out-a-saved-wifi-password-on-android.html)

[Link2](http://www.guidingtech.com/29149/view-saved-wifi-password-android-ios/)

The link provides about the data folder, yes there is a folder name data, but there is no folder named misc and wifi inside the data folder and the file wpa_supplicant.conf is also not anywhere. I have only two folders i.e. fka and log.

Comment: If somebody who don't have the answer please avoid but don't down the question.

Comment: This Link might help you out. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21296/how-can-i-find-a-saved-wi-fi-password

Comment: So I have to root my phone to see the files that's tricky and long process that is not good in android at least still thanks @Ask some how it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to data/misc/wifi folder and you will find a file named wpa_supplicant.conf. Tap on the file to open it up and make sure you use ES File Explorer 's built-in text/HTML viewer for the task. In the file you should be able to see the network SSID and their passwords next to it.

Comment: Dear the links I have provided has already the solution same as you mentioned, yes there is a folder name data, but there is no folder named misc and wifi inside the data folder and the file you are telling wpa_supplicant.conf is also not anywhere. I have only two folders i.e. fka and log. I updates the question again please refer it.